# How to get document Id from selected Item in flutter's dropDownMenu

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

I want to get a document Id from the firestore when the user selects a dropdown item of the drop-down menu in flutter, I tried some logic but they are not worked for me.

**This is my code**

```
Widget cityDropDown() {
    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('city').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return const Center(
            child: const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
          );
        return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
          items: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: document.data['name'],
              child: new Text(document.data['name']),
            );
          }).toList(),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null) {
              return 'Please choose your city';
            }
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(
              () {
                _city = value;
                _society = null;
                _building = null;
                _houseNumber = null;
                _userStatus = null;
                _occupancyStatus = null;
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All of this is psuedo-code
In this section:

```
value: document.data['name'],
child: new Text(document.data['name']),
```

You can instead have value be the document itself instead of also being the text value of the name. Then you could add something like this in this section of the code:

```
onChanged: (value) {
            **aPersistentVariablePreviouslyDeclared = value.id;**
            setState(
              () {
                _city = value.data["name"];
                _society = null;
                _building = null;
                _houseNumber = null;
                _userStatus = null;
                _occupancyStatus = null;
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
              },
            );
          },
```

Comment: I think you try to say I have to change the value of value and text to document instead of document.data['name'], Then it not shows the city list in the drop-down its shows "instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'" If I am wrong to understand your solution then let me know.